# Find first and last business day in R or Mysql

Tags: mysql, r

I'm looking to get a list of the first and last business days of the month.
Its basically a list of business days:

```
2009-01-03
2009-01-04
2009-01-05
...
```

I just want to get a list of the first and last days, basically and max and min day(date) for each year-month combination.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Taking (country-specific) holidays into account?

Comment: Is your starting point a list of all working days in a month?

Comment: Yes, I just need the first and last day in each month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question states that you already have a list of business days and that you need a way of finding the minimum and maximum for each year-month combination.

You can use `ddply` in package `plyr` to do this.  I also make use of package `lubridate` because it has some convenience functions to extract the year and month from a date.

Create some data:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- sample(seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"), by="1 day", length.out=365), 100)
df <- data.frame(date=x, year=year(x), month=month(x))
```

Now extract the min and max for each month:

```
library(plyr)

ddply(df, .(year, month), summarize, first=min(date), last=max(date))

   year month      first       last
1  2011     1 2011-01-03 2011-01-30
2  2011     2 2011-02-03 2011-02-19
3  2011     3 2011-03-06 2011-03-29
4  2011     4 2011-04-09 2011-04-30
5  2011     5 2011-05-01 2011-05-29
6  2011     6 2011-06-04 2011-06-28
7  2011     7 2011-07-02 2011-07-29
8  2011     8 2011-08-10 2011-08-30
9  2011     9 2011-09-01 2011-09-28
10 2011    10 2011-10-07 2011-10-31
11 2011    11 2011-11-01 2011-11-28
12 2011    12 2011-12-01 2011-12-30
```